# EC scalar multiplication with Strauss-Shamir method

Tags: algorithm, multiplication, elliptic-curve

I am searching informations about the so called "Strauss-Shamir method" for scalar multiplication upon elliptic curves. It is a method to compute `k1 · P + k2 · Q` in around log<sub>2</sub>(`k`) additions and doublings, where `k1, k2 < k`.

Unfortunately, while this algorithm is cited left right and center, the *actual* algorithm (and, dare I hope, its analysis) is not cited anywhere. Is there someone that could explain it to me, or at least give me a link on pseudocode/analysis?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To multiply a number **P** by an **n**-bit scalar **k**, you can use doubling and addition according to the binary expansion of **k**.  Let's say that **k=9**.  In binary, that's `1001`, and you can calculate **9P** like this:

```
R=0
R=R*2+P  //the most significant '1' bit
R=R*2    //next bit is 0
R=R*2    //next bit is 0
R=R*2+P  //next bit is 1
```

The Strauss-Shamir trick is just calculating **aP + bQ** by doing the additions inside the chain instead of outside.   Let's say that, in binary, `a=1001` and b=0011`. Then we just do this:

```
R=0
R=R*2+P   //bits from a,b = 1,0
R=R*2     //bits from a,b = 0,0
R=R*2+Q   //bits from a,b = 0,1
R=R*2+P+Q //bits from a,b = 1,1
```

If you precompute **P+Q**, then this doesn't take much longer than a single multiplication.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!